# Get HTML text and create PHP variable?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm relatively new to PHP. I'm wondering if it's possible to simply create a variable from an HTML element like a `<p>` tag or a `<div>`?

All I'm looking for is a string variable which I can then use to register a new user through WordPress. I have all of the user information available to me in JavaScript variables and displaying on the page.

If this isn't possible I'm not quite sure how I would go about using AJAX to do a simple conversion to get those JS variables to PHP variables.

The code is quite long at this point, filled unrelated stuff. All that I have on the page that is related is a box displaying 3 `<p>` tags (each of which are also available already as JS variables - which I'm trying to pass into the `wp_create_user` function.

Comment: You should know a server-side scripting language (PHP in case of WordPress) if you want to use the AJAX techniques. So unless you have some code for this... we can't really help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you right, you're talking about "variable variables"

just take any string and use it as variable's name. Use double $$ sign for this.

quick example:

```
$var = 'hello';
$$var = 'world';

echo $hello; // > this will output 'world'
```

Comment: I'm not following. I'm trying to create a variable from existing text in a <p> tag (similar to var = ..... .text() in jquery. However, I'm trying to do this in PHP. How does the above allow for this?

Comment: // HTML
<p id="username">John Doe</p>

// jquery
var username = $('#username').text();

// php (wordpress)
wp_create_user('$username', '$password', '$email');


Just need to pull "John Doe" string (currently available as JS variable as well as already being displayed onscreen / "ready" when the PHP command is called). The simplest way I can see to do this is to pull the text from inside the <p> and assign a PHP variable, then pass that to the wordpress create user command. Thanks everyone!

Comment: jquery scripts starts to work AFTER php script has completed its loading. So to pass back a variable from jQuery to PHP you have to use ajax call:

$.post(ajax_url, {username: username, password: password}, function(data){ ... });

read more about Ajax + WordPress: http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX